# XML::LibXML findnodes is not returning any matched node

Tags: perl, libxml2

I have a simple XML without namespace.

I am using XML::LibXML::Reader to parse the XML. When I get the matched Element, I finish the search. As I understand this element is of type XML::LibXML::Element.
(I have certain limitation to continue with XML::LibXML::Reader)

When I am trying to use findnodes with xpath, it's not working. 
Here is the code

```
my $libXMLPattern = XML::LibXML::Pattern->new('widget');
my $element;

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(string => $xml);
$reader->nextElement();

while ($reader->nextPatternMatch($libXMLPattern))
{
    next if ($reader->nodeType == XML_READER_TYPE_END_ELEMENT);
    $element = $reader->copyCurrentNode(1);
        last;
}
$reader->finish();


    my $xPathExp = '//component';
    my @nodes = $element->findnodes ($xPathExp);
```

Here is the XML

```
<widget name="a" type="b">
<component type="C">
    <component type="ca"/>
    <component type="cb"/>
</component>
</widget>
<window>
...
</window>
```

Please help me what wrong I am doing?

Comment: There are two problems with your question, [please edit it to improve](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8356949/edit). ① We cannot run this program to see what the problem is. Provide example data and fill in the variables which you're using but not declaring. ② "not working" is a bad description. Instead, explain what you expect to see, and what really happens.

Comment: @daxim "not working" is a horribly bad description.

Comment: Apologies for missing information. I updated it with XML content and filled variable with values. Please have alook at it.

Comment: @rpg: Your data isn't valid XML... So no parser will accept is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use XML::LibXML::Reader qw( XML_READER_TYPE_END_ELEMENT );

my $xml = <<'__EOI__';
<widget name="a" type="b">
  <component type="C">
    <component type="ca"/>
    <component type="cb"/>
  </component>
</widget>
__EOI__

my $libXMLPattern = XML::LibXML::Pattern->new('widget');

my $element;
my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new( string => $xml );
while ($reader->nextPatternMatch($libXMLPattern)) {
   next if $reader->nodeType == XML_READER_TYPE_END_ELEMENT;
   $element = $reader->copyCurrentNode(1);
   last;
}
$reader->finish();

die if !$element;

say $_->getAttribute('type') for $element->findnodes('.//component');
```

Output:

```
C
ca
cb
```

The key is `//component` vs `.//component`.

```
//component
```

is short for

```
/descendant:component
```

Well, the element doesn't exist in a document, so there's no `/` to start from. On the other hand,

```
.//component
```

is short for

```
./descendant:component
```

which is long for

```
descendant:component
```

That path is relative to an existing node, so it can be processed.

Next time, please provided the *minimal* and *runnable* piece of code that demonstrates the problem.